# C - Passing Variable Value through Pointer Passes Unknown Long

Tags: c

I am a currently learning C and am stuck on a problem I was assigned. 
I have to create a function with a parameter of a int pointer, where the user can input an int, and then print out the int in the main method. Currently, I am able to input data and print it out properly within the method itself. However, when the data passes to the main function, it always prints "32766". How can I approach this problem? Thanks for your help.

```
int main(void) {
  int a;
  funct2(&a);
  printf("Int is %d", a);

}

void funct2(int *a){
  int d;
  printf("Enter an Integer:: ");
  scanf("%d", &d);
  printf("%d\n", d);
  a = &d;
```

}

Comment: change `a = &d` to `*a = d`  . And turn on compiler warnings

Comment: @M.M that fixed it exactly! I was under the impression that they mean the same thing with different syntax. Why does *a work and not the one with &d? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first one makes a local pointer point to a different place, the second one writes a value to where the pointer is currently pointing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `a = &d;` to try to return your integer via pointer. Unfortunately that sets a in `funct2` to point to `d` instead. What you want is `*a = d;`.